# Passing class method to CreateThreadPoolWork

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I am trying to make a call to `CreateThreadPoolWork()` and the first parameter is a function. I am calling the function inside of a class and I want the thread to execute a function that is inside my class.

```
class A{
public:
    void print() {
        std::cout << "Hello";
    }

    void ctpw() {
        ...
        PTP_WORK pw = CreateThreadPoolWork((PTP_WORK_CALLBACK)print, nullptr, &tpenv);
        ...
};
```

The above does not work. If I set `print` to `static` it will work however any variables in the method that need to reference the class properties won't have access.

The only option I can think of is to create a struct and pass an pointer to the class instance and a pointer to the data I need to pass to the thread function. Was hoping it was possible without doing this.

Comment: it's not possible without doing this

Comment: You can only call a non-static meter function with a pointer or reference to **an object**. What object will `CreateThreadPoolWork` use? In the standard library, the constructor for `std::thread` understands member functions, and when you create a thread object and pass a pointer to member function it expects the next argument to be a pointer or reference to an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CreateThreadPoolWork()` takes a C-style function pointer.  You can't pass it a non-static class method, only a standalone function or a static class method.

However, it does accept a user-defined value as a `void*` pointer, which you can use to pass in the `this` pointer of your object.

Try this:

```
class A{
public:
    void print() {
        std::cout << "Hello";
    }

    VOID CALLBACK do_print(PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE Instance, PVOID Context, PTP_WORK Work) {
        static_cast<A*>(Context)->print();
    }

    void ctpw() {
        ...
        PTP_WORK pw = CreateThreadPoolWork(&A::do_print, this, &tpenv);
        ...
};
```